# No longer able to view the design tab in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

After i started a new project in android studio (Blank Activity), the display tab disappeared and i was not able to run the application no longer. I believe the problem is here:

[image: [1]]

Do you have any advice on how to resolve this problem?!

Answer (score 1):

do you have this compile

```
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

in your Module.App gradle file ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to ConstraintLayout's documentation, there you can find out how to configure your project to use it:

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#add-constraintlayout-to-your-project